# Shell context menu item added to Registry but doesn't appear in right click!

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, registry, windows-shell

I have an application that adds two menu items to the shell context menu of "jpegFile".
I can see that it is correctly added to the registry but in some machines it doesn't appear when user right clicks a jpeg file!

I'm using [Windows 7]
and I'm adding items to registry via my application's setup project.

Any idea why?

Comment: Is there any notable difference between those machine and the machines on which it works correctly? (OS version, 32/64 bit, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably caused incorrect registry.

Try registering your extension under

> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Blah Blah]
>   @="Edit with Blah Blah"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Edit with Blah
>   Blah\command] @="\"C:\Program Files\BlahBlah.exe\" \"%1\""