# Add Explorer Shell Context Menu for jpegfile in 64-bit OS?

Tags: contextmenu, jpeg, explorer

How do you add windows explorer shell context menu to 64-bit OS like this example here [Simple Context Menu](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/SimpleContextMenu.aspx?fid=332633) for jpg files?

Why doesn't adding the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jpegfile\shell\Simple Context Menu\command\path to exe` work like it does in 32-bit?  People have told me it's because you can't access 32-bit `exe` but I'm pointing it to a 64-bit `exe`?  Can you not do this in 64-bit OS?  Why is it so simple in 32-bit??

Found this user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569041/shell-context-menu-item-added-to-registry-but-doesnt-appear-in-right-click) on stackoverflow with same problem but no solution.

Can you not simply add it like you do in 32-bit OS?